# Exclusive access to AudioUnit in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiounit

I was thinking is it possible to get exclusive access to AudioUnit record (end possibly playback) device, to assure that any other proccess will not gain access to it while my is working (eventually even in background)?

Any advice would be helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Even Apple's own apps?

Comment: Couldn't this keep users from hearing/answering their phones?

Comment: It could. But it's kinda point of it. Eventually it should handle any requests for the recording device, like to see if any app is trying to get access to it, and handle any interruptions.

Answer (score 1):

Your app can get exclusive access to an audio session when in the foreground.  When another app comes to the foreground, it can do the same and thus kill your apps access to audio.  The Phone app can also take control of audio by interrupting your app.  No way to prevent this on stock OS iOS devices.

Comment: Could you tell me how to monitor which application is trying to gain access to the Audio unit? Also, is the recording device given to process exclusively by default or I need to do some addidional coding for this?